# Migrating a GWT 2.5 web app to Java 10

Tags: java, java-10, gwt-2.5

I have a substantial web-app that is built using GWT-2.5.1 and Java 8. With the deprecation of Java 8, I need to migrate this to Java 10 / 11.

I've managed to get past a few issues, but I've hit one I cannot get past.

When building the app, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Compiling module com.<xxx>
[INFO]    [ERROR] Unable to find type 'java.lang.Object'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits
    'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by
    inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

Looking at the gwt.xml files, it looks correct to me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to="xxxx">
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
    <inherits name="com.XXXXCoreBase" />
    <!-- Delete non-0inherits stuyff -->
</module>

<!-- XXXXCoreBase -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.query.Query"/>
    <!-- Other module inherits -->
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.gen2.gen2" />
    <inherits name="com.Microsoft" />
    <inherits name="org.Org" />

    <source path="client" />
    <source path="shared" />

</module>
```

This compile quite happily with Java 8. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

According to the *[Release_Notes_2_8_2](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_2)*

> Supports running in Java 9. Note that this does not yet mean that GWT
>   can compile Java 9 sources, or support the Java 9 JRE changes, but
>   that a Java 9 JRE can be used to compile a GWT project. Do note that
>   the new `--module-path` flag is not supported, but `-classpath` must still
>   be used as in the past.

and the [discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/WuoGvsjud1o) -

> If you aren't using java 9 modules, the latest release will work.  It
>   does this by reading the classpath from
>   System.getProperty("java.class.path"), so if you are using standard
>   tools for creating classpath, everything should work fine.  If you are
>   doing anything non-standard for assigning classpaths, or if you are
>   using java 9 modules (i.e. you supply a modulepath instead of
>   classpath), this will very likely not work for you.

It seems as if, the most you can do is to upgrade to ***gwt-2.8.2***, with a restriction of using just the classpath and not making your application modular.

Also, here is a read further for the [Java10 support discussion.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/DiGNHTKKe6Y)