# Maven Compile GWT & OpenJDK 11

Tags: java, maven, gwt

Recently, I am trying to switch my project to use OpenJDK 11, however the Maven build is failing because one of the GWT modules is failing to compile.

The project currently uses GWT 2.6.0, and I've tried updating to 2.8.2 if any of the newer versions is compatible with OpenJDK 11. The build is run from Eclipse IDE 4.9.0

When running with 2.6.0, the following error occurs:

```
Compiling module XXXXModule
[INFO]    Looking for precompiled archives.  To disable, use -Dgwt.usearchives=false
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/User.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/regexp/RegExp.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/event/Event.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/xml/XML.gwtar
[INFO]    Loading archived module: jar:file:/C:/Users/XXXX/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.6.0/gwt-user-2.6.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/json/JSON.gwtar
[INFO]    Found 0 cached/archived units.  Used 0 / 0 units from cache.
[INFO]    Compiling...
[INFO]       Compilation completed in 0.00 seconds
[INFO]    Added 0 units to cache since last cleanup.
[INFO]    Validating units:
[INFO]    Removing invalidated units
[INFO]    Checked 0 dependencies for errors.
[INFO]    [ERROR] Unable to find type 'java.lang.Object'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
[INFO] Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
....
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.6.0:compile (default) on project tlm-war: Command [[
[ERROR] C:\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -classpath .... -localWorkers 4 -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen C:\Users\XXXX\gitrepos\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX\target\.generated XXXXModule XXXXModule XXXXModule XXXXModule
```

But investigating XXXXModule.gwt.xml, the file does include 'Core'

```
<module>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
    <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt" />
....
```

I did some investigation online, and according to this answer, [Migrating a GWT 2.5 web app to Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877006/migrating-a-gwt-2-5-web-app-to-java-10), I should try upgrading to GWT 2.8.2, but the build gets another issue:

```
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.LambdaExpression"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:1150)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:905)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1014)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
[INFO]  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.<init>(GwtAstBuilder.java:3881)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GwtAstBuilder.process(GwtAstBuilder.java:3970)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:129)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:336)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:470)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:1040)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:325)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:548)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:479)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:465)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:222)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:202)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:143)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:204)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:155)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:144)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:125)
```

Has anyone else been successful in compiling GWT 2.6-2.8.2 with OpenJDK 11?

EDIT:

Snippet of pom.xml

```
....
<properties>
  <gwt.version>2.8.2</gwt.version>
  <smartgwt.version>2.4</smartgwt.version>
</properties>
....

<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <configuration>
          <modules>
            <module>XXXXModule</module>
            <module>XXXXModule</module>
            <module>XXXXModule</module>
            <module>XXXXModule</module>
          </modules>
          <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
          <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Classpath:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-servlet\2.8.2\gwt-servlet-2.8.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.8.2\gwt-user-2.8.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\jsinterop\jsinterop-annotations\1.0.2\jsinterop-annotations-1.0.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\jsinterop\jsinterop-annotations\1.0.2\jsinterop-annotations-1.0.2-sources.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\smartgwt\smartgwt\2.4\smartgwt-2.4.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\smartgwt\smartgwt-skins\2.4\smartgwt-skins-2.4.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.6\slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.6\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.6\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.1\logback-classic-1.1.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.1\logback-core-1.1.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\jasypt\jasypt\1.9.2\jasypt-1.9.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.3.5.Final\hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.3.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging-annotations\1.2.0.Beta1\jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\4.0.4.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\1.1.0.Final\jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-jpamodelgen\4.3.5.Final\hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.5.Final.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-tools\4.3.1.CR1\hibernate-tools-4.3.1.CR1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.3.1.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.8\freemarker-2.3.8.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\jtidy\r8-20060801\jtidy-r8-20060801.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\tycho\org.eclipse.jdt.core\3.9.1.v20130905-0837\org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.9.1.v20130905-0837.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\text\3.3.0-v20070606-0010\text-3.3.0-v20070606-0010.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\core\commands\3.3.0-I20070605-0010\commands-3.3.0-I20070605-0010.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\equinox\common\3.6.200-v20130402-1505\common-3.6.200-v20130402-1505.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\oracle\jdbc\ojdbc6\11.2.0.3.0\ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ucp\ucp\11.2.0.3.0\ucp-11.2.0.3.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\mysema\querydsl\querydsl-sql\2.8.2\querydsl-sql-2.8.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\mysema\querydsl\querydsl-core\2.8.2\querydsl-core-2.8.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\11.0.2\guava-11.0.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\mysema\commons\mysema-commons-lang\0.2.4\mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib\2.2\cglib-2.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\1.6\joda-time-1.6.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jdbc-core\1.0.0.RELEASE\spring-data-jdbc-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.0.0.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.1\commons-beanutils-1.9.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.10\commons-configuration-1.10.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\3.2.9.RELEASE\spring-test-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.1\txw2-2.3.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.7\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8\stax-ex-1.8.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.15\FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-xjc-plugin\3.2.3\cxf-xjc-plugin-3.2.3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\sonatype\plexus\plexus-build-api\0.0.7\plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-utils\2.0.5\plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-archiver\1.2\plexus-archiver-1.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-container-default\1.0-alpha-9-stable-1\plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\classworlds\classworlds\1.1-alpha-2\classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\plexus\plexus-io\1.0.1\plexus-io-1.0.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\shared\maven-artifact-resolver\1.0\maven-artifact-resolver-1.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-xjc\2.3.0\jaxb-xjc-2.3.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.3.0\jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.3.0\jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\xml-resolver\xml-resolver\1.2\xml-resolver-1.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.18.2-GA\javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\xml\ws\jaxws-api\2.3.0\jaxws-api-2.3.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\xml\soap\javax.xml.soap-api\1.4.0\javax.xml.soap-api-1.4.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\7.0.91\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.91.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-annotations-api\7.0.91\tomcat-annotations-api-7.0.91.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-jasper\7.0.91\tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.91.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\core\compiler\ecj\4.4.2\ecj-4.4.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\7.0.91\tomcat-embed-el-7.0.91.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-logging-log4j\7.0.91\tomcat-embed-logging-log4j-7.0.91.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\7.0.91\tomcat-embed-websocket-7.0.91.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-fileupload\commons-fileupload\1.2\commons-fileupload-1.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1.1\activation-1.1.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.8.2\gwt-dev-2.8.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.6.2\gson-2.6.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm\5.0.3\asm-5.0.3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-util\5.0.3\asm-util-5.0.3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\5.0.3\asm-tree-5.0.3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\5.0.3\asm-commons-5.0.3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\colt\colt\1.2.0\colt-1.2.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\ant\ant\1.6.5\ant-1.6.5.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\com\ibm\icu\icu4j\50.1.1\icu4j-50.1.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\tapestry\tapestry\4.0.2\tapestry-4.0.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit\2.19\htmlunit-2.19.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.2\serializer-2.7.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.4\commons-lang3-3.4.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.1\httpclient-4.5.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.3\httpcore-4.4.3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.1\httpmime-4.5.1.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\htmlunit\htmlunit-core-js\2.17\htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\nekohtml\nekohtml\1.9.22\nekohtml-1.9.22.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\cssparser\cssparser\0.9.18\cssparser-0.9.18.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\w3c\css\sac\1.3\sac-1.3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-client\9.2.13.v20150730\websocket-client-9.2.13.v20150730.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-util\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-io\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-common\9.2.13.v20150730\websocket-common-9.2.13.v20150730.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-api\9.2.13.v20150730\websocket-api-9.2.13.v20150730.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-webapp\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-webapp-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-xml\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-xml-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlet\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-security\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-server\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-http\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-http-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-servlets\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-servlets-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-continuation\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-continuation-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-annotations\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-annotations-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-plus\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-plus-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\jetty-jndi\9.2.14.v20151106\jetty-jndi-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\apache-jsp\9.2.14.v20151106\apache-jsp-9.2.14.v20151106.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\toolchain\jetty-schemas\3.1.M0\jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jasper\apache-jsp\8.0.9.M3\apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar
C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\org\mortbay\jasper\apache-el\8.0.9.M3\apache-el-8.0.9.M3.jar
```

Now I did notice that gwt-dev and ecj jar does have LambdaExpression with the same package. But I removed ecj and I still get the same issue. Apache-jsp jar does have a LambdaExpression but different package so I doubt that is the issue.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is only exactly that one copy of the eclipse JDT on your classpath? Without reproducing it locally, this seems like the most likely suggestion. Additionally, prior to GWT 2.8.2, versions of GWT may work beyond Java 9, changes were made with that release to support running in that environment.

Comment: So I did check to see if there was another jar that contained the same class and package. There was one being included by a local jar, which I then excluded, but I still see the same issue.

Comment: As Ignacio put in an answer (and I put in my last remark) there is no way that this old of a GWT version will work with a recent JDK anyway. Can you confirm that you are updated and that there are no conflicts in your other dependencies (multiple versions of gwt, etc), and perhaps share your pom.xml or the output of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbse=true`?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I did indeed update to the 2.8.2, and that's where I am seeing the SecurityException above And yes, I checked the dependency tree but did not see any duplicate dependencies.

Comment: As I said, we'll need more details then - there is a duplicate, it is just a question of where it is, that's what this error means. Either the pom.xml so we can reproduce, or a list of the dependencies so we can help narrow it down.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, here is an update of the pom and classpath that is run during the maven goal.

Comment: The gwt plugin isnt enough to see what other dependencies you have - and your dependency list includes `org\eclipse\tycho\org.eclipse.jdt.core\3.9.1.v20130905-0837\org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.9.1.v20130905-0837.jar` which almost certainly has a copy of that class as well, as well as `org\eclipse\jdt\core\compiler\ecj\4.4.2\ecj-4.4.2.jar`. If you need to have other copies of the JDT, you should split your project into "client" vs "server" so they don't conflict like this.

Comment: I did check in that jar as well, and can confirm it does not have a LambdaExpression class.

Comment: Can you update your question with accurate information then, including how you obtained the classpath being given to the gwt-maven-plugin? At this point, the question is kind of all over the place. Removing that ancient version of tycho will almost certainly be necessary anyway, since it will conflict with either that or other classes within the newer JDT used by GWT. To reiterate the answer already posted, GWT 2.8.2 is required if you want to use Java 9+, so either update your question to just using 2.8.2 (and your correct list of deps, your entire pom, the current build log) or focus on 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

`GWT 2.8.2` works with `openjdk11`. [Here](https://travis-ci.org/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin) you can see that the tbroyer gwt-maven-plugin works with `openjdk8` and `openjdk11` using both last GWT release (version `2.8.2`) and last development commit (version `HEAD-SNAPSHOT`).

So, you really should upgrade to `GWT 2.8.2`. GWT only support the last version. Usually upgrading between version is trivial because almost no API changes have been made for years and only bug fixes and new java language support has been added. It should be quite easy.

In your case, it seems to be a dependency problem, maybe because some of your dependencies have a dependency on the old version of GWT itself. To avoid dependencies conflicts it is recommended to use the BOM dependency. [This tutorial](https://dev.to/ibaca/modern-gwt-first-steps-509k) includes a minimal explanation of why and how to use the GWT BOM dependency. Essentially, add this in your root project `pom.xml`:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I added the dependencyManagement section into the pom, but that did not resolve the issue. It's really strange, I checked all of the jars in the classpath if there was a duplicate LambdaExpression class. There was one, so I removed the jar but I still the same issue regardless, so I am honestly very confused as to what the issue is.

Comment: So after some additional investigating, I think I agree with you that GWT 2.8.2 probably should work with OpenJDK 11. However, I did discover that apparently there is a different version of the gwt-maven-plugin. [Mojo](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/). According to their site, the tboyer version you provided is a newer implementation of the gwt-maven-plugin. So I'm wondering if  the Mojo implementation is not compatible with OpenJDK 11. Is there anyway to confirm?

Comment: You should use the tbroyer one, the mojo plugin had some problems specially it is not multi-module friendly. The tbroyer one + the tbroyer gwt maven archetype for multimodule projects is the best solution for maven projects right now. Anyways, the mojo plugin works at least in Java 9 https://travis-ci.org/gwt-maven-plugin/gwt-maven-plugin.

Comment: After some initial testing, it does seem like switching to the tboyer version does seem to work better OpenJDK 11. However, just to be sure, are you able to start a build with OpenJDK 11 to confirm the Mojo plugin is not compatible? Then I can mark your response as the answer.