# Updating Vaadin project's GWT for Java 11

Tags: gwt, vaadin, java-11, vaadin8

I'm unable to build my maven project with vaadin and gwt components with **JDK 11**.

I've updated the **gwt-user** and **gwt-dev** to latest (**2.8.2**) version.

I'm using Vaadin7, tried with Vaadin8 also. Try to compile with the vaadin-maven-plugin.

The output of my maven build :

```
[ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

I saw related questions but nothing working for me.

Can this stack work with Java 11 ? It works up to Java 8.

**EDIT :**
To compile with JDK11, you'll need gwt-user, gwt-dev and vaadin-maven-plugin to 2.8.2. Then you'll need to upgrade Vaadin to Vaadin 8.9.1.

Comment: what is in your pom.xml? Also this question is about exactly the same issue : [GWT Java11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962230/maven-compile-gwt-openjdk-11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the GWT dependencies to 2.8.2 is not enough. You also need to use a version of `vaadin-maven-plugin` that is based on GWT 2.8.2. I don't remember exactly which version number was the first one that works, but I have personally had errors with Vaadin 8.0 whereas everything has worked for me with Vaadin 8.8.

Comment: It works after upgrading to the latest Vaadin8 version (8.9.1). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to setup your Vaadin 8 project to support Java 11 both in server and client side (i.e. GWT) code, you need to patch the project to use GWT 2.9.0.

Vaadin recently published [documentation about how to do this in their blog](https://vaadin.com/blog/update-your-vaadin-8-project-to-java-11-and-gwt-2.9.0).

Short summary

To upgrade your Vaadin 8 application to use GWT 2.9.0, add the following property:

```
<vaadin.gwt.version>2.9.0</vaadin.gwt.version>
```

Then add the dependencies to your pom.xml. If you have a multi-module project, you need to choose the module which defines the widgetset.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.gwt.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
             <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.gwt.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

There is one breaking change in GWT 2.9.0, but it is easy to patch it locally. You need to work with the module that contains your client-side code. Add this class to package `com.google.gwt.dev.shell`:

```
package com.google.gwt.dev.shell;

public final class CheckForUpdates {
    // NOP
}
```

Furthermore there is full multimodule proof of concept application in GitHub https://github.com/TatuLund/gwt290-demo

Answer (score -2):

GWT 2.8 does not work JDK 11, so the widgetset compilation will not work. You'll need to rely on JDK 8.

Comment: GWT 2.8.2 does work with Java 9-12 as far as I can tell, at least for compiling java to js.

Comment: You probably need to restrict the source level of Java to 1.8