# Eclipse GWT SDK 2.8.2 with Java11

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, java-11

We run a webserver (Jetty9) with openJDK11 (openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14).
Our GWT-webapp project is built using Eclipse with GWT-SDK 2.8.2 and also openJDK11.

But the server delivers the following error message:

---

HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /. Reason:

Service Unavailable

Powered by Jetty://

---

We tried to configure the project using Maven and using plain project configuration by Eclipse, the result is the same.

When we configure and build both with JDK8, it works fine.

According to
[Maven Compile GWT & OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962230/maven-compile-gwt-openjdk-11)
GWT2.8.2 and JDK11 should work together.
But we do not have any compiler-errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside:: nice username :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is solved.

The problem occured with Raspian Stretch and separately installed JDK11.
Using Raspian Buster (which has JDK11 as standard) it works.