# Maven GWT module breaks with GWT 2.8.2 + Java 11

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have a maven artifact which has code for a GWT module.  The contents of the `GwtModule.gwt.xml` file are (in summary):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='mygwtmodule'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />

    <!-- Other module inherits go here -->

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />
</module>
```

The `gwt.xml` file is in `src/main/java/my/module`, and the entrypoint which implements `com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint` is in `src/main/java/my/module/client/MyModule.java`.

I then use this code in a servlet project, importing the other artifact as one of my `<dependencies>`.  The servlet project has a `src/main/resources/my/webapp/GwtWebapp.gwt.xml` file, which contains only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='myservlet'>
    <inherits name='my.module.GwtModule' />

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='my.module.client.MyModule' />
</module>
```

And this configuration has worked fine for years, using both 2.7.0 and 2.8.0 versions of GWT and the corresponding maven plugin.

But now I've upgraded to Java 11, which requires the Maven GWT 2.8.2 plugin, and all of a sudden it fails.  Changing only the GWT version to `2.8.2` in both project, running `mvn install` on the GWT module, and running `mvn gwt:compile` in the servlet project gives me:

```
.
.
[INFO] Compiling module my.webapp.GwtWebapp
[INFO]    Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    Finding entry point classes
[INFO]       [ERROR] Hint: Check that the type name 'my.module.client.MyModule' is really what you meant
[INFO]       [ERROR] Hint: Check that your classpath includes all required source roots
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
```

Any help identifying the root of this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: set the logLevel to 'TRACE', run the GWT compile again and search the compile log again

Comment: Are you using the [Bill of Materials dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53971794/2970947) on GWT?

Comment: `Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.` - can you please edit your compile to turn on strict? Depending on your plugin, it might be <strict>true</strict> or <failOnError>true</failOnError>, check the docs please. As a rule of thumb, always have this feature turned on, as it will ensure that your dev mode experience is as fast as possible, by avoiding errors that cause the compiler to redo work each time.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for some reason, the source files were not being included in the `.jar` file.  I had to explicitly add:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.java</include>
            <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

To the `<build>` section of my GWT module.

Looking at the `.jar`s created by an earlier version, it seems that the source was being included by the plugin, but that something had changed which meant it was no longer the case.